# Intermittent Xamarin.iOS crash with no exception thrown

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, crash, xamarin.forms

I have created a Xamarin.Forms barcode scanning app with Android and iOS projects. The Android build appears to run fine, but the iOS build occasionally crashes and I am struggling to pin down the cause, as no crash log is produced and no exception is reported in the application output.

Under heavy load (non-stop barcode scanning) the app crashes after typically 200 or 300 barcodes have been scanned.

I am puzzled how such a crash can occur, leaving absolutely no evidence of its cause. Is there somewhere else I should be looking for the evidence, apart from within Xcode's Devices window? Shouldn't I expect an exception to be reported in the application output, while debugging?

I have implemented logging handlers for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` but they don't appear to be called. Is there some other way I can instrument my code to trap the cause of this crash?

Many thanks for your advice,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

To get some output I always hit the continue button in visual studio debugger. The application stops, and for some reason I can see an exception in the output. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was previously debugging using Xamarin Studio (on Mac). But, based on your suggestion, I switched to using Visual Studio (on Windows), as I have also seen that hitting the Continue button can reveal additional diagnostic detail. Unfortunately, for this issue, when the app crashed, Visual Studio simply reports "The app has been terminated". The Continue button is not enabled, since the debugging session is actually still running in Visual Studio. Once I hit the Stop button, everything is lost.

Comment: Maybe you can find some more details in Xamarin Profiler. For example a rising amount of used memory when scanning hunderts of barcodes?

Comment: Yes, it's true that there is a memory leak, which I have seen in Xcode Instruments and appears to be caused by the barcode scanner SDK. I have reported a bug to the vendor and I'm waiting for their fix. However, this surely cannot be the cause of this crash, because I have seen a couple of occasions where the app crashes within the first few scans. It's very frustrating not to have access to any diagnostic detail to know what's really happening.